# How do I export a HAR file from CefSharp

Tags: cefsharp, har

I have CefSharp (WinForms) to display a browser for UI Testing. I want to implement some functionality to automatically save the network requests as HAR File - similar to chrome devtools, when you access the network tab.

I could not figure out if this is possible using some of the handlers in the CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser (for example by implementing RequestHandler).  But there I do not see any timing information.

Comment: You have two options, implement a RequestHandler, proxy the requests and save them to disk and serve them to the browser or implement a response filter, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#response-filtering

Comment: There is a third option, use puppeteer to do something like https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1916 you can connect puppeteer sharp to an existing browser instance, not tested, not sure if all the functionality has been implemented in the c# port.